# How to change the default @@STATE key for storage plugin

Tags: local-storage, ngxs

I use `@ngxs/storage-plugin` to sync app states into localstorage. The default storage key for serialized states is `@@STATE`, is there a way to rename the default key?

I noticed when calling `NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot`, I can use `key` option to change storage key of a slice of states, but it was not working when I try to store the whole states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` option should have been named `path` instead. It does not refer to the name of the key used in localStorage. Despite the fact that `@@STATE` also creates a key in localStorage of the same name.

The `key` option is one or more dot notations into the state store. For example;

```
interface MyModel { example: string }

@State<MyModel>({
    name: 'app',
    defaults: { example: "Hello World" }
) //...
```

If the key is set to `@@STATE` then the storage will save

```
   "@@STATE" : "{app: {example: 'Hello World'}}"
```

When you change the key it has to point into the state object otherwise it will yield `undefined`. So we can set `key` to `"example"` which would store `"Hello World"` in localStorage under the key named "example".

Like this

```
   "example": "Hello World"
```

As of now, the value `@@STATE` is hard coded in the plugin and can not be renamed. It holds special meaning to serialize the entire store. Otherwise, the key must be a dot path into the state object.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't override the '@@state' constant, what you can do is modify the engineering used to save the state. In the service that you build to manipulate the storage you can enter the key that you prefer.

your module

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([AuthState], {
      developmentMode: !environment.production,
    }),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot({ disabled: environment.production }),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({ storage: StorageOption.SessionStorage }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: STORAGE_ENGINE,
      useClass: MyStorageEngine,
    },
  ],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

and in your service class

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyStorageEngine implements StorageEngine {
  readonly yourKey = '@@YOUR_KEY';
  constructor(private storageService: YourStorageService) {}

  get length(): number {
    return this.storageService.length;
  }

  getItem(key: string): any {
    return this.storageService.getItem(this.yourKey);
  }

  setItem(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.storageService.setItem(this.yourKey, value);
  }

  removeItem(key: string): void {
    this.storageService.removeItem(this.yourKey);
  }

  clear(): void {
    this.storageService.clear();
  }
}
```